# How do I turn a 2x3 matrix into a 3x3 matrix

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, matrix-inverse

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I just can't find the answer I need.
I have the following matrix:-

```
 A  |6 6 0|
    |9 0 0|
```

Each column represents co-ordinates on a grid.
Now to find the inverse of "A" I need to create this into a 3x3 square matrix, to do this I add 001 as the 3rd row...

```
 B  |6 6 0|
    |9 0 0|
    |0 0 1|
```

I do this simply because it is what I have seen in the online examples.

My question is, what is the method to calculate/add the 3rd row of a 2x3 matrix in this situation?

Comment: What language/environment are you using? It should be as simple as creating a row vector filled with zeros that's as long as the matrix, setting the last number in the row vector to a one, and then appending it to the matrix...

Comment: I am just using some simple 2d transformations, beyond that I'm not sure what you mean by environment. Ok, would I always set the last number to 1?

Comment: I was asking what tool(s) are you using? (matlab, octave, etc) And yes, if you are always just adding a single row to the bottom of your matrix then the last number in the row should always be 1, if what you're actually doing is appending the last row of a 3x3 identity matrix. Could you link to the example that you're following?

Comment: This is my own example, but say I plotted the triangle onto a graph with the co-ordinates above (A) I then multiply the point matrix (A) by the transformation matrix (1 0/0 -1) to achieve a reflection in the x axis, to reverse this operation I need to find the inverse. Hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to take the inverse of a matrix that is not squared..
I assume that would like to just extend the matrix in order to make i squared, the reason why you use the [0 0 1] is to make the matrix consistent..

Actually you matrix represent two equations with three variables..

```
A:

    6*x_1 + 6*x_2 + 0*x_3 = 0
    9*x_1 + 0*x_2 + 0*x_3 = 0
```

this is not consistent
but by adding the last row you get

```
B:

    6*x_1 + 6*x_2 + 0*x_3 = 0
    9*x_1 + 0*x_2 + 0*x_3 = 0
    0*x_1 + 0*x_2 + 1*x_3 = 0
```

this matrix exists on echelon form

```
[1 0 0]
[0 1 0]
[0 0 1]
```

so by adding the last row you are not changing the matrix

you would properly get same result just by reduce it to

```
[6 6]
[9 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
s = size(A);
B = eye(max(s));
B(1:s(1),1:s(2)) = A
```